# SQL Convert function manipulation in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to convert several instances of the CONVERT function of SQL in to the INPUT functions in `SAS`.

The existing portions of code (from SQL) that I need to convert in to instances of `INPUT` functions in `SAS` are:

```
Convert(Date, APP_DATE_AJUDICATED ) as  APP_DATE_AJUDICATED

Convert(Date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1,  APP_DATE_AJUDICATED )+0, -1)) as ME_Decision_Date

Convert(Date, DateAdd(D,1, APP_DATE_AJUDICATED ))
```

Comment: Define the meaning of the `CONVERT()` function. What flavor of SQL were you using before? What database?

Comment: What type of variable is APP_DATE_AJUDICATED?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert a datetime value into a date value then use the `DATEPART()` function.

```
dt='01JAN2019:00:00'dt;
date=datepart(dt);
```

If you are converting text to values use the INPUT() function with an appropriate informat. You you are converting values to text then use the PUT() function with an appropriate format.

```
str='01JAN2019';
date=input(str,date9.);
str2=put(date,yymmdd10.);
```